# I don’t know how to solve the last pieces

Tags: rubiks-cube, solvability

So, I almost finished a rubik’s cube, but the last 3 pieces are not in their places (green on red face, blue on green face, and red on blue face). Apart from these, the other faces are done.

[image: The proof]

How can I finish solving the cube?

Comment: This was closed as a duplicate of a question about a situation where _just two_ cubelets were swapped. It is not a duplicate of that question; here the permutation is a 3-cycle. I've reopened it.

Answer (score 5):

If the three edge pieces you want to rotate are on the top layer at front, left and right, then the move $F^2UM^{-1}U^2MUF^2$ will permute them cyclically where $F$ means rotating the front face $90^{\circ}$ clockwise (so $F^2$ means rotating it $180^{\circ}$), $U$ means rotating the top (*upper*) face $90^{\circ}$ clockwise, and $M$ means rotating the vertical "middle slice" perpendicular to the front face $90^{\circ}$ towards you. See [here](https://ryanstutorials.net/rubiks-cube-tutorial/step-five-final-layer.php) for an animation.

This will move front $\rightarrow$ left $\rightarrow$ right $\rightarrow$ front which is actually the reverse of the direction you want; so either do it *twice* or do it *backwards* meaning $F^2U^{-1}M^{-1}U^2MU^{-1}F^2$. (Take the steps in reverse order, inverting each one, noting that e.g. $F^2$ is its own inverse.)

Comment: Thank you!I solved the cube without help,but thanks for sharing a few minutes to help me!I really appreciate it!I forgot an essential detail:after finishing the second layer i forgot to make sure i have the second square on the third layer on their right faces(that's after i made the yellow cross).And right after that i did the R algorithm for every unfinished corner and that's it.I had the cube solved for the first time conscious.

Comment: @AdrianU. Tip: Use the check mark under the voting buttons to mark Gareth's answer as accepted.